# gtk styles not behaving properly

Tags: python, coding-style, gtk

I was attempting to mess with the style of a `Button`, and noticed that my changes were making the button look strange. To make sure I was doing the right thing, I tried doing what I thought would be semantically a no-op:

```
button.set_style(button.get_style())
```

However, the button style changes dramatically after this line. I'm on Windows 7. Without this line, it looks like a regular windows 7 button - rounded, nice gradient, light-blue on highlight, etc. After the line, it looks like an ugly old Windows XP button - blocky, no gradient, and lightly colored on highlight. What gives?

Comment: Any GTK warnings/errors in the console output? What happens with `.set_style(None)`?

Comment: ah `.set_style(None)` reverts it to the Windows 7-looking one. the `set_style` docs apparently mention that styles interact badly with themes, as the latter replace the former.. that would explain my problems. do you have any pointers on how to change attributes of a theme?

Comment: Changing the style works for me on Windows XP (using GTK+ 2.20 and the MurrinaNeoGraphite theme). Which theme and GTK version are you using?

Comment: @AndiDog: I didn't say it doesn't work, I just said it makes the button different. are you sure the color didn't change at all? the GTK button seems to look a lot more like the XP one than the Vista one, maybe the difference is just not noticeable? Otherwise, I am using GTK 2.14, so maybe that's why.

Comment: Setting a custom style (other than `None`) leads to the same problems that you have (buttons look flat and ugly). Seems like you just can't use styles with GTK themes.