# gtk: indicate a button should be pressed

Tags: python, user-interface, coding-style, gtk

What's the best way to indicate on a GTK interface that a button should be pressed / to "highlight" the button? The use case is that I have a set of checkboxes representing various settings, but for them to take effect, they must be submitted to a server. I want to indicate that the currently checked settings have not been sent to the server, by, for example, highlighting the Submit button to be red.

I tried messing with the button style to change its color conditionally, but I [ran into problems there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3711286/gtk-styles-not-behaving-properly).

Comment: Another answer to a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69954711/16775594

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps you could disable the button (so that it "greyed out") until all the checkboxes have been set or whatever... This is quite a common approach.

Answer (score 1):

You could set the button's label to be bold when there are changes to be submitted:

```
button.get_child().set_markup('<b>Submit</b>')
```