# How do I highlight a button in Gtk?

Tags: python, button, gtk

I notice that in many of the system dialogs on Ubuntu, there is a button (usually <kbd>Open</kbd>, <kbd>Save</kbd>, etc.) that is a different color than normal. But also, these buttons' colors change with the system theme; in Adwaita, they are blue. In Yaru, they are green. So no, I'm not asking how to set the background of a button to a *specific* color.

My question is, how do I make a button highlighted according to the current theme without having to manually set the color? Is it even possible to do this in Python? I've looked in `Gtk`, `Gtk.Dialog`, `GtkSource`, `Gdk`, `GLib`, and `Pango`, and found nothing. Ideally, the solution would work for any button, not just a button in a dialog.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `StyleContext` to highlight widget. Gtk widgets such as `Gtk.Button` that inherits from `Gtk.Widget` can obtain its `StyleContext` by calling [get_style_context](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/Gtk-3.0/classes/Widget.html#Gtk.Widget.get_style_context). You can then add `class`(a str) to the context by calling [add_class](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/Gtk-3.0/classes/StyleContext.html#Gtk.StyleContext.add_class) on it. gtk itself provides `suggested-action` and `destructive-action`. You can also define your own style class.

Below is an example using `suggested aciton`.

```py
import gi

gi.require_version("Gtk", "3.0")
from gi.repository import Gtk

win = Gtk.Window()

box = Gtk.Box()
button1 = Gtk.Button(label="button1")
button2 = Gtk.Button(label="button2")
box.pack_start(button1, True, True, 0)
box.pack_start(button2, True, True, 0)

button1_style_context = button1.get_style_context()
button1_style_context.add_class('suggested-action')

win.add(box)
win.connect("destroy", Gtk.main_quit)
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

[image]

Comment: I think the default adiwata theme shows "destructive-action" as red. Perhaps you are using a different theme.

Comment: Wait... it was in your answer the whole time! Goodness, I must be blind :-)! Thanks for the help! And yes of course, it works.